# How does Kafka-streams execute parallel operations inside a Task?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Say we have a kafka-streams topology like:

```
                  inputTopic
                       |
                       |
                      \ /
                 Kstream-source 
                     /   \
                    /     \
                   |       |
                   |       |
             process1     process2
                   |       |
                   |       |
                topic1    topic2
```

Where the same KStream object resulting from reading the topic is used in 2 different parallel process nodes,

and `process1` appears before `process2` in the topology code.

Within the task `0`, does kafka-streams always execute `process1` then `process2` on events ? (because the task is within a thread, I assume there is a deterministic choice done during development)

And say we have 2 events `evt1` and `evt2` published on `inputTopic, partition 0`.

Does the stream Task finish all transformations on `evt1` before starting transformations on `evt2` ?

Comment: Thread execution ordering isn't determined by "order of topology code"

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's what I suppose. But any idea about the internal algorithm ?

Comment: Personally, I don't know. You're welcome to look at the open source code

Answer (score 0):

The task executes within a java thread.

It receives events one at a time, applies all transformations on that event, then move on to the next event.

The transformations are executed *in the order they appear in topology code* (like any ordinary thread)

I checked this any way by having 2 `peeks` on the same KStream. Making a for-loop in the first one, displaying a message in each iteration. The second `peek` displays another string.

Execute such test as many times as you want. The print in the *second* `peek` appears every time after all the prints in the for-loop of the *first* `peek`

*Note: This test is still not satisfying as it assumes if it works n times then it works all the time*

Edit: After checking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61748676/is-the-processing-order-of-a-kafka-streams-topology-specified), I am requestionning this